# h2o.importFile() does not import full data frame in R

Tags: r, h2o

I have a dataframe of 50 rows (subjects) and 572288 columns (variables)

When parsing the `data.frame` into an h2o object I lose variables and end up with
51 rows and 419431 variables.

It does not change if I reduce the number of rows or increase them.

```
library("data.table")
library("h2o")
options("h2o.use.data.table"=T)
h2o.init()
trainset=as.data.frame(matrix(ncol=572288,nrow=50,1))
fwrite(trainset, "train.csv", sep=",")
train=h2o.importFile("train.csv", sep=",")
dim(trainset)
dim(train)
```

My output is:

```
> h2o.init()
 Connection successful!

R is connected to the H2O cluster:
H2O cluster uptime:         1 hours 2 minutes
H2O cluster timezone:       Europe/Berlin
H2O data parsing timezone:  UTC
H2O cluster version:        3.18.0.11
H2O cluster version age:    3 months
H2O cluster name:           H2O_started_from_R_chiocchetti_lub856
H2O cluster total nodes:    1
H2O cluster total memory:   9.84 GB
H2O cluster total cores:    24
H2O cluster allowed cores:  20
H2O cluster healthy:        TRUE
H2O Connection ip:          localhost
H2O Connection port:        54321
H2O Connection proxy:       NA
H2O Internal Security:      FALSE
H2O API Extensions:         XGBoost, Algos, AutoML, Core V3, Core V4
R Version:                  R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)

> trainset=as.data.frame(matrix(ncol=572288,nrow=50,1))
> fwrite(trainset, "train.csv", sep=",")
>
> train=h2o.importFile("train.csv", sep=",")
|======================================================================|100%
> dim(train)
[1]     51 538177
> dim(trainset)
[1]     50 572288
```

It seems to me that I am running in some kind of memory issue when reading back the lines from the file. However, I have no idea how to overcome this problem.

The final aim is to do a randomForest.

Comment: Try allocating more memory in `h2o.init(max_mem_size = '12G')`, or another value larger than the default allocation of 9.84 GB, that's feasible on your system. If you get more rows/columns, you know that's the problem.

Comment: unfortuantely this had no effect at all still i get the same result
I went up to 24GB

The only difference I notice is if I use the original data (which is filled with value 0 1 or 2) or the dummy matrix. But not matter how much memory I allocate the error is reproduced

Comment: Try reading your data in using `data.table::fread()` (`fread` for speed, but you could also use `read.csv`), then setting `as.h2o()`

Comment: Make sure that `fread` returns a *50 x 572,288* table

Comment: I was able to reproduce your issue for the version of h2o you are using and for the latest, as posted below this is probably a bug. It would be interesting however if you could keep reducing the number of columns you have and see where the issue goes away (I tested the same code for a smaller matrix and then h2o worked as expected). Thanks!

Comment: reading the data back in with  'data.table::fread()' works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

This is likely a bug; I've created a jira ticket for it here: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-5860.

please feel to update the ticket if you have a jira account.

Comment: Thank you very much... i updated the title (it adds one row and deltes several colums) and specified that data.table::fread() works as it should